# Octave; JAVA enabled and packages

Tags: octave

I've just finished Eng Degree so making the cross over from MATLAB to OCTAVE. I have a script I want to keep using that pulls table data into matrix form using java. This works in MATLAB but not in OCTAVE, I changed the initial MATLAB script from;

```
urlText = java.lang.String (urlread (url_string));
```

To the OCTAVE format

```
urlText = javaObject ("java.lang.String (urlread (url_string))", 1.001);
```

The java isn't recognised so I was reading about installing packages but this doesn't seem to necessary as JAVA is part of the core of OCTAVE now. I think JAVA is working as I write this line;

```
a = javaObject ("java.lang.Double", 1.001);
```

Which returns;

```
<Java object: java.lang.Double>
```

1. Any idea on how to get the java.lang.String working?

   I've been at this hours so thought I'd try and work around and install a new package which has caused it's own problems as I can't seem to find the correct way to install the package. I tried placing the package in the following directory;

   ```
   C:\Octave\octave-4.2.1\share\octave\packages
   ```

   Then running the command `pkg install` however it doesn't find the package.
2. is there a specific directory this should be in? Different method to install a package?

   I then checked to see if I had any packages installed pkg list, I don't depsite having packages in the directory.
3. have I missed something in the installation for these packages to be enabled?

Any input on these issues would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks Allan

Comment: Have you spotted [this section in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Java-Interface.html#Java-Interface)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `javaObject` methods takes a 'class-type' argument, and optional 'inputs to the constructor' arguments. Your syntax is wrong.

```
a = javaObject("java.lang.String", urlread("http://google.com")).toString()
```

works for me.

As for packages, the `.tar.gz` files you have are supposed to be in the path (preferably current directory) and installed using `pkg install`.

In general though, it's probably easiest to pass the `-forge` option to have it all downloaded and installed automagically, e.g.

```
pkg install image -forge
```

Comment: PS. unless that was bad copy/pasting here, I can't even begin to guess what you were expecting back from `javaObject ("java.lang.String (urlread (url_string))", 1.001); ` :p

Comment: Thanks Tasos, I'm travelling atm but will give this a go when I get a chance, thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi Tasos, the pkg install worked fine and you were correct about the syntax problem, Java works fine though there's now some larger issue with the function, thanks for the input.